# Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libhdf5.9.dylib

Tags: homebrew, hdf5, pytables

After "brew upgrade", I found I cannot use Pytables on my Mac.

```
import tables as tb 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-57032f570037> in <module>()
----> 1 import tables as tb

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/__init__.py in <module>()
 80 
 81 # Necessary imports to get versions stored on the cython extension
 ---> 82 from tables.utilsextension import (
 83     get_pytables_version, get_hdf5_version, blosc_compressor_list,
 84     blosc_compcode_to_compname_ as blosc_compcode_to_compname,

 ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libhdf5.9.dylib
 Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so
 Reason: image not found
```

I found that instead of having **libhdf5.9.dylib** in the directory, I have **libhdf5.10.dylib** now.

I can uninstall and install **hdf5** without a problem and I also tried to reinstall **tables**.

I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reinstall `tables`. If you are using a recent version of pip, you also need to make sure you don't use a cached version of pytables that was built against the old libhdf. You can do this with `pip install -U --force-reinstall --no-binary tables tables`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by installing the developing version from GitHub:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables.git@develop#egg=tables
```